# Advanced PHP Regex - Parse Wordpress Post Content

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to extract some text from wordpress post.Here is a code that doesn't work, i guess probably because the regex, which works fine on Expresso, yet it doesn't work on PHP.

```
$content = get_the_content();
preg_match('\<form id="form1.*?(?=<zmfj>)\', $content, $matches);
$setupform = $matches[0];
echo $setupform;
```

In this case the variable content could be:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="http://google.com"><zmfj>
```

So the extraction result should be

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="http://google.com">
```

Comment: Wrong syntax, check manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: Well, you should see what's wrong after posting the code :)

Comment: Which regex should i use then. I tried in an online php tester but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you considered using an HTML parser instead of a regex?

Comment: The clue is in the syntax highlighting, check the code on your question. Then check the manual to find out the correct syntax in PHP.

Comment: I do not think an HTML parser is needed. If what i want to extract is surrounded with lets say erqwerqw and rasrrwrwq, then what php regex should be?

Comment: Ok, but why simple one doesn't work - $content = "zmfjdsadasdasdas";
preg_match("/zmfj/", $content, $matches);
echo $matches[1];

Comment: I mean if this doesn't work nothing works.

Comment: @Zox - in your comment example, you want echo $matches[0].

Comment: Thanks. i have found this just few mins ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/<form[^>]+>/", $content, $matches);
//the [^>]+ bit matches consecutive characters that are not ">"
```

Comment: Nah, very simple. Regexps are very powerful, I recommend this interactive tutorial: http://regexone.com/ Who said learning isn't fun?